# how to select val? [priv]

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins

[UPDATE]

Hi! This is a more detailed question based on my first question. So I want to change my map pointers on page 2 based on the selected options the user has selected in page 1.

Example: User selects umbrella on page 1, clicks 'Find Now' button and shows map pointers 'Clementi 7-11' and 'Cheers Buona Vista' on the map in page 2. 
However, if user selects lip balm on page, clicks 'Find Now' button, it will show user map pointers 'SP 7-11' and 'Cheers Bouna Vista' on the map in page 2.

Currently, my problem is that no matter what the user has selected in page 1, it will always show map pointers 'Clementi 7-11' and 'Cheers Buona Vista' on the map in page 2.

(I am not sure why when u run snippet, it does not show the dropdown of options but I could do it in my VSC and I also could show my Google Maps, and the map pointers)

```js
var arr = [{
    img: 'umbrella.png',
    item: 'Umbrella',
    price: '$10',
    value: 1,
    qty: 0
  },
  {
    img: 'lipbalm.png',
    item: 'Lip Balm',
    price: '$5',
    value: 2,
    qty: 0
  },
  {
    img: 'flu.png',
    item: 'Flu Medication',
    price: '$5',
    value: 3,
    qty: 0
  },
  {
    img: 'glucose.png',
    item: 'Glucose Sweets',
    price: '$1',
    value: 4,
    qty: 0
  }
];
var globalIndex = 0;

//Page 1 Select
function populateOptions() {
  console.log('populateOptions');

  var o = "";
  $.each(arr, function(index, val) {
    console.log("index:" + index);
    var item = arr[index].item;
    o = o + "<option value='" + arr[index].value + "'>" + item + "</option>";
    console.log(arr[index].value)
  });
  $("#myOption").html(o);
  $("#myOption").selectmenu("refresh");
};

$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function() {
  populateOptions();
  $('#myOption').on('change', function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    if (this.value == 2) {
      $('option').attr('value', 2);
    } else if (this.value == 3) {
      $('option').attr('value', 3);
    } else if (this.value == 4) {
      $('option').attr('value', 4);
    } else {
      $('option').attr('value', 1);
    }
    console.log(arr[globalIndex].value)
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("load", "#page2", {
      role: "page"
    });
  });
  $("#myOption").selectmenu("refresh", true);

});

//Page 2
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page2", function() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: {
      lat: 11.3083,
      lng: 103.7776
    },
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
  });
});

// //Umbrella Stores     
var umbrellaPoints = [{
    latitude: 1.315680,
    longitude: 103.764976,
    title: "Clementi 7-11",
    content: "<h3>Clementi 7-11</h3>"
  },

  {
    latitude: 1.307567,
    longitude: 103.789972,
    title: "Cheers Buona Vista",
    content: "<h3>Cheers Buona Vista</h3>"
  },
];

// //Lip Balm Stores
var lipBalmPoints = [{
    latitude: 1.311639,
    longitude: 103.778665,
    title: "SP 7-11",
    content: "<h3>SP 7-11</h3>"
  },

  {
    latitude: 1.307567,
    longitude: 103.789972,
    title: "Cheers Buona Vista",
    content: "<h3>Cheers Buona Vista</h3>"
  },
];

// //Flu Medicine Stores
var fluMedPoints = [{
    latitude: 1.303444,
    longitude: 103.792011,
    title: "Cheers Biopolis Street",
    content: "<h3>Cheers Biopolis Street</h3>"

  },

  {
    latitude: 1.311639,
    longitude: 103.778665,
    title: "SP 7-11",
    content: "<h3>SP 7-11</h3>"
  }
];

// //Glucose Sweets Stores
var gluSweetPoints = [{
    latitude: 1.315680,
    longitude: 103.764976,
    title: "Clementi 7-11",
    content: "<h3>Clementi 7-11</h3>"
  },

  {
    latitude: 1.303444,
    longitude: 103.792011,
    title: "Cheers Biopolis Street",
    content: "<h3>Cheers Biopolis Street</h3>"

  }
];


function findMe() {
  $('#popupDialogue').popup();
  $('#popupDialogue').popup('open');
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onFindSuccess, onError);
};

function onFindSuccess(position) {
  $('#popupDialogue').popup('close');
  var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
    position.coords.longitude);
  var mapProp = {
    center: latlong,
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapProp);
  var content = "<h3>You are here</h3>";
  var title = "Your position";
  addMarkersToMap(map, latlong, title, content);
}

function onError(error) {
  alert("Encounter an error")
}

function addMarkersToMap(map, latlong, title, popcontent) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlong,
    map: map,
    title: title
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: popcontent
  });

  infowindow.open(map, marker);
}

function showPoints() {
  var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(1.311166, 103.775583);
  var mapProp = {
    center: latlong,
    zoom: 14,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapProp);

  $('#findNow').click(function() {
    console.log(this.value)

  });
  console.log(arr[globalIndex].value);

  if (arr[globalIndex].value == 1) {
    $.each(umbrellaPoints, function(index, val) {
      var latlong2 = new google.maps.LatLng(val.latitude, val.longitude);
      addMarkersToMap(map, latlong2, val.title, val.content);
    });
  } else if (arr[globalIndex].value == 2) {
    $.each(lipBalmPoints, function(index, val) {
      var latlong3 = new google.maps.LatLng(val.latitude, val.longitude);
      addMarkersToMap(map, latlong3, val.title, val.content);
    });
  } else if (arr[globalIndex].value == 3) {
    $.each(fluMedPoints, function(index, val) {
      var latlong4 = new google.maps.LatLng(val.latitude, val.longitude);
      addMarkersToMap(map, latlong4, val.title, val.content);
    });
  } else if (arr[globalIndex].value == 4) {
    $.each(gluSweetPoints, function(index, val) {
      var latlong5 = new google.maps.LatLng(val.latitude, val.longitude);
      addMarkersToMap(map, latlong5, val.title, val.content);
    });
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD7WcthdB_FxP0wUX1rRgJCDHiw2IpqUz0"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Page 1 -->
  <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="page1main" style="margin-top: 250px;">
      <label for="select">Tell me what are you looking for today:</label>
      <select name="select" class="selectItem" id="myOption"></select>
      <br>
      <button style="width: 70%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" id="findNow">
              <a href="#page2" data-transition="flip"onclick="showPoints()">Find Now</a>
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Page 2 -->
  <div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
      <a href="#page1" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>
      <h1>Google Maps</h1>
      <a data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">Go back</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div id='content'>
        <p><button class="ui-button" onclick="findMe()">Find Me</button></p>
        <p><button class="ui-button" onclick="showPoints()">Places of interest</button></p>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupDialogue" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Map loading...</h1>
      </div>
      <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h3 class="ui-title">Retrieving current position... please wait</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: I see no relationship between the option that gets selected and the point on the map. When a User selects an item, jQuery can and will need to tell the Google Map where the Pin is, and what details to display. At this time, I do not see those details anywhere in the script or data. You need to provide more information.

Comment: Also your snippet does not work properly as you are using Relative URL links in the head when you need to use the full URL.

Comment: use `pagecontainershow` not `pagecreate` because the latter runs once, unless you append a new page on each selection.

Comment: @Omar it doesn't work, my Options list will disappear

Comment: `pagecontainercreate` to populate the list. `pagecontainershow` to show the map.

Answer (score 0):

`globalIndex` never changes, it remains 0. `arr[0].value` is 1, therefore `arr[globalIndex].value` is also 1. You might want to update `globalIndex` via `this.value`

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function () {
    populateOptions();
    $('#myOption').on('change', function() {
    console.log( this.value );
    globalIndex = this.value;
    if (this.value == 2){
        $('option').attr('value', 2);
    } else if (this.value == 3){
        $('option').attr('value', 3);
    } else if (this.value == 4){
        $('option').attr('value', 4);
    } else {
        $('option').attr('value', 1);
    }

    // $('#myOption').attr('value', 'this.value');   
    console.log(arr[globalIndex].value) 
    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "load", "#page2", { role: "page" } );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example is not very clear and the logic is also not clear as it is such a limited example. Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = [{
      img: 'umbrella.png',
      item: 'Umbrella',
      price: '$10',
      value: 1,
      qty: 0
    },
    {
      img: 'lipbalm.png',
      item: 'Lip Balm',
      price: '$5',
      value: 2,
      qty: 0
    },
    {
      img: 'flu.png',
      item: 'Flu Medication',
      price: '$5',
      value: 3,
      qty: 0
    },
    {
      img: 'glucose.png',
      item: 'Glucose Sweets',
      price: '$1',
      value: 4,
      qty: 0
    }
  ];

  function populateOptions(d, tObj) {
    console.log("Populate Options", tObj.attr("id"));
    tObj.html("");
    $.each(d, function(i, v) {
      $("<option>", {
        id: "select-opt-" + (i + 1),
        value: v.value
      }).html(v.item).appendTo(tObj);
    });
    tObj.selectmenu("refresh");
  };

  $("#myOption").selectmenu();
  populateOptions(arr, $("#myOption"));

  $('#myOption').on('change', function() {
    var p = $(this).val();
    console.log("Selected", p);
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("load", "#page" + p, {
      role: "page"
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
<div data-role="page">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="page1main" style="margin-top: 250px;">
    <select name="select" class="selectItem" id="myOption"></select>
  </div>
</div>
```

It was not making sens the way that you were using `$.each()`.

> The `$.each()` function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array. In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time.

The value in this case is an Object. So you do not need to use the index to get to the Object, it's already available. See More: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

The `<option>` elements are create via jQuery and append them to the target Object as the array data is iterated.

**Update**

It might be better to make a more complex data set.

```js
var itemData = {
  Umbrella: {
    img: "umbrella.png",
    item: "Umbrella",
    price: 10,
    locations: [{
        latitude: 1.315680,
        longitude: 103.764976,
        title: "Clementi 7-11",
        content: "<h3>Clementi 7-11</h3>"
      },
      {
        latitude: 1.307567,
        longitude: 103.789972,
        title: "Cheers Buona Vista",
        content: "<h3>Cheers Buona Vista</h3>"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Lip Balm": {
    img: "lipbalm.png",
    item: "Lip Balm",
    price: 5,
    locations: [{
        latitude: 1.311639,
        longitude: 103.778665,
        title: "SP 7-11",
        content: "<h3>SP 7-11</h3>"
      },
      {
        latitude: 1.307567,
        longitude: 103.789972,
        title: "Cheers Buona Vista",
        content: "<h3>Cheers Buona Vista</h3>"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Flu Medication": {
    img: "flu.png",
    item: "Flu Medication",
    price: 5,
    locations: [{
        latitude: 1.303444,
        longitude: 103.792011,
        title: "Cheers Biopolis Street",
        content: "<h3>Cheers Biopolis Street</h3>"
      },
      {
        latitude: 1.311639,
        longitude: 103.778665,
        title: "SP 7-11",
        content: "<h3>SP 7-11</h3>"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Glucose Sweets": {
    img: "glucose.png",
    item: "Glucose Sweets",
    price: 1,
    locations: [{
        latitude: 1.315680,
        longitude: 103.764976,
        title: "Clementi 7-11",
        content: "<h3>Clementi 7-11</h3>"
      },
      {
        latitude: 1.303444,
        longitude: 103.792011,
        title: "Cheers Biopolis Street",
        content: "<h3>Cheers Biopolis Street</h3>"
      }
    ]
  }
};

$(function() {
  function populateOptions(d, tObj) {
    console.log("Populate Options", tObj.attr("id"));
    tObj.html("");
    var i = 1;
    $.each(d, function(k, v) {
      $("<option>", {
        class: "select-opt-" + i,
        value: k
      }).html(k).appendTo(tObj);
      i++;
    });
    tObj.selectmenu("refresh");
  };

  function findMe() {
    $('#popupDialogue').popup();
    $('#popupDialogue').popup('open');
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onFindSuccess, onError);
  };

  function onFindSuccess(position) {
    $('#popupDialogue').popup('close');
    var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
      position.coords.longitude);
    var mapProp = {
      center: latlong,
      zoom: 18,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapProp);
    var content = "<h3>You are here</h3>";
    var title = "Your position";
    addMarkersToMap(map, latlong, title, content);
  }

  function onError(error) {
    alert("Encountered an error");
  }

  function addMarkersToMap(map, latlong, title, popcontent) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latlong,
      map: map,
      title: title
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: popcontent
    });

    infowindow.open(map, marker);
  }

  function showPoints() {
    var latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(1.311166, 103.775583);
    var mapProp = {
      center: latlong,
      zoom: 14,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapProp);
  }

  $('#findNow').click(function() {
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("load", "#page2", {
      role: "page"
    });
  });

  $("#myOption").selectmenu();
  populateOptions(itemData, $("#myOption"));

  $('#myOption').on('change', function() {
    var item = itemData[$(this).val()];
    console.log("Selected", item);
    var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map-canvas")[0], {
      center: {
        lat: -34.397,
        lng: 150.644
      },
      zoom: 8
    }), latlong;
    $.each(item.locations, function(i, l) {
      latlong = new google.maps.LatLng(l.latitude, l.longitude);
      addMarkersToMap(map, latlong, l.title, l.content);
    });
    showPoints();
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyD7WcthdB_FxP0wUX1rRgJCDHiw2IpqUz0"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Page 1 -->
  <div data-role="page" id="page1">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content" id="page1main" style="margin-top: 250px;">
      <label for="select">Tell me what are you looking for today:</label>
      <select name="select" class="selectItem" id="myOption"></select>
      <br>
      <button style="width: 70%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;" id="findNow">
              <a href="#page2" data-transition="flip">Find Now</a>
            </button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Page 2 -->
  <div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header">
      <a href="#page1" class="ui-btn ui-icon-home ui-btn-icon-left ui-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>
      <h1>Google Maps</h1>
      <a data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-iconpos="left">Go back</a>
    </div>
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div id='content'>
        <p><button class="ui-button" onclick="findMe()">Find Me</button></p>
        <p><button class="ui-button" onclick="showPoints()">Places of interest</button></p>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="popup" id="popupDialogue" data-dismissible="false" style="max-width:400px;">
      <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Map loading...</h1>
      </div>
      <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <h3 class="ui-title">Retrieving current position... please wait</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</html>
```

The above example will no0t work properly due to the way the snippet works. You can see here that the `itemData` is a structured object. This allows you to tie in relative data for each item, like store locations that carry that product. If you have a much larger number of locations, you might consider performing a AJAX request back to the server to search / retrieve the location list.

When a selection is made, the markers are added for those locations. When the User hits "Fine Now", Page 2 will be loaded and should contain the map with the markers on it.

Comment: what is tObj for?

Comment: Hi! I have just updated my question, hopefully it is more detailed for you to understand :)

Comment: @Sunny `tObj` is a parameter name for the "Target Object". This function would allow you to pass in a jQuery Object to append the new `<option>` elements to. I also updated my answer.